# How do I set icons for Air for Android Settings within Flash CS5?

Tags: android, flash, air, icons, flash-cs5

Hey there- I'm trying to set my own icons for Air for Android using Flash CS5. I see the icon tab within the Air Android Settings panel, but it won't let me navigate to my icons.  Also, I would add the path to my manifest.xml file, but it gets overwritten while publishing.  Thanks, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I found that I needed to install the latest version of the Adobe Flash Pro CS5 Extension for AIR 2.5.  Once installed, my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are using the latest Adobe Flash Pro CS5 Extension for AIR 2.5.